# Rewrite of IDA decompiled function

Tags: c, disassembly

I'm looking for help to rewrite this IDA decompiled function to C code.

```
int random_generated_number;
sub_8049A96(&random_generated_number, 11); //Passes address of random_generated_number and int 11

int __cdecl sub_8049A96(int a1, int a2)
{
  int result;
  int i;

  for ( i = 0; i < a2; ++i ) // loop 11 times
    *(i + a1) = byte_8049C4E[rand() % 10u]; // Cast byte pointer (i + a1) = select rand number between 0 to 9. I don't really understand what *(i + a1) is doing. could you explain?
  result = a2 + a1; Set result = 11? is this correct?
  *(a2 + a1) = 0; // What is this doing?
  return result; Returns 11?
}
```

So far, I have come up with this,

```
int test(int a1, int a2)
{
    int result;
    int i;

    char byte_8049C4E[48];

    for (i = 0; i < a2; ++i)
        *(i + a1) = byte_8049C4E[rand() % 10u];
    result = a2 + a1;
    *(a2 + a1) = 0;
    return result;
}
```

But upon compilation I get illegal indirection. Can anyone help? Also if anyone is able to give a detailed explanation of what the function is doing it would be much appreciated? I have in-lined my comments, would like to know if they are right or not.

Comment: This function fills a2 bytes, starting from a1 (which is interpreted as pointer), with values from byte_8049C4E array (using random indexes from 0 to 9). Finally, it sets byte #a2+1 to 0 and returns address of this byte. The point here, what address is passed to the function as a1 parameter. Generally, looks like a good way to crash the program.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I have also roughly come to the same conclusion, but I don't understand why the need to set byte #12 to 0. It is because of the calling convention where the cdecl has to clean up the stack? Or is it normal that the byte after the last is set to 0? Also I have copied this decompiled code from IDA. I'm guessing the address passed is an empty memory space such that it can be filled. No crashing involved here.

Comment: I don't see absolutely no reason to set 11 bytes to `byte_8049C4E[rand() % 10u]` values. So, setting byte #12 is meaningless as well. Maybe this is random string generation? I have no idea. Calling convention is not related here.

Comment: Maybe header should be `char *test(char *a1, int a2)`... and the function might write a null-terminated string of length `a2` consisting of randomly selected digits from '0'..'9' (if that's what's in the byte array), returning a pointer to the end of the string?  The decompilation may have changed pointers to integers if they're the same size.

Comment: Right on, @Dmitri! What is the data at `8049C4E` in the executable?

Comment: .rodata:08049C4E ; char byte_8049C4E[]              .rodata:08049C4E byte_8049C4E    db 30h

Comment: Yeah, that's the ASCII code for a `0`. There must be more than that, though -- the address is used as an *array*.

Comment: Sorry please check here for more http://pastebin.com/NTii55cv

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the function generates a string of random digits, and equates to something like this:

```
/* write a string of len digits to s, and return a pointer to
   the end of the string (for further appending) */
char *test(char *s, int len)
{
    char *digits = "0123456789";

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        s[i] = digits[rand() % 10];
    s[i] = '\0';
    return &s[i];
}
```

..though `digits` could contain something else, depeding on what's stored in `byte_08049C4E[]`.  If it really was passed a random address in the first parameter, it may crash the program and certainly wouldn't do anything useful.

Comment: How would I know when I read the decompiled code if int should be changed to a char *pointer ? You mention the decompilation may have changed pointers to integers if they are the same size, but how would I know?

Comment: re: pointers vs. int: You need to figure it out from the way it's used.  If it's being dereferenced, it'd be a pointer (look for `*` and `[]`).